# How to save the path of a file in firebase database in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am capturing the image and uploading it to the firebase storage. I also want to save the path of that file to the firebase database so that I can use the image to other places by using that path from the database.
The code I am using to upload the image is `

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            mprogress.setMessage("Uploading image..");
            mprogress.show();
            Uri uri =data.getData();
            final StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                   mprogress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Upload is done...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can get file path from UploadTask.TakeSnapshot variable like this and upload to database:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                       mprogress.dismiss();
                     // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                       Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                     //This is a sample database structure you need to create your own
                      mDatabase.child("users").child("profileImage").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get filePath using `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();` which is return   `Uri` you can get complete path via calling `Uri.toString();`

Call `uploadFileAndSaveToFireBase(uri)` method inside your `onActivityResult`

```
private void uploadFileAndSaveToFireBase(Uri pathUri) {
    mprogress.setMessage("Uploading image..");
    mprogress.show();
    // Get a reference to store file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>
    StorageReference photoRef = chatPhotosStorageReference.child(pathUri.getLastPathSegment());
    // Upload file to FireBase Storage
    photoRef.putFile(pathUri).addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            mprogress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Upload is done...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
            String strFilePath=downloadUrl.toString();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: did not upload file");
            mprogress.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```